# Specific \epigraph style

Tags: epigraphs

I'm trying to create the `\epigraph` shown in the picture. I want to place it at the bottom right of an empty page with the style shown in the picture. I'm using the code. How can I modify it to get what I want? I don't want a line between the quote and the source ... basically the style shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathabx}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}
\epigraph{Begin at the beginning, the King said gravely, ``and go on till you come to the end: then stop.''}{Lewis Carroll, \textit{Alice in Wonderland}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution consists in patching some `epigraph` internal commands, with the `etoolbox` package, so that the default font shape for the epigraph text be italic (in an upshape context):

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathabx}
    \usepackage{ebgaramond}
    \usepackage{epigraph}
    \renewcommand\textflush{flushright}

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \makeatletter
    \newlength\epitextskip
    \pretocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
    \apptocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\epigraph}{\@epitext{#1}\\}{\@epitext{#1}\\[\epitextskip]}{}{}
    \makeatother

    \setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
    \setlength\epitextskip{2ex}
    \setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}

    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}

    \vspace*{\fill}
    \epigraph{For the Snark \emph{was} a Boojum,  you see.}{Lewis Carroll, \emph{The Hunting of the Snark}
    }

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 25):

All you need to add to your code is

```
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\epigraph{\itshape Begin at the beginning, the King said gravely, ``and go on till you come to the end: then stop.''}{---Lewis Carroll, \textit{Alice in Wonderland}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it seems to me that "Begin at the beginning," needs to have quotes around it; otherwise the quote is disjointed.  (i'm not familiar enough with `epigraph` to have any other comments.  i was thrown off by the absence of a closing quote after "beginning," in the original question, thinking that maybe `epigraph` provided the "outside" quotes, but i think that's not the case.)

Answer (score 7):

Not the answer to your question, but a solution with KOMA-Script.

[image]

Option 1:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setkomafont{dictumtext}{\itshape\small}
\setkomafont{dictumauthor}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\dictumwidth{.75\linewidth}
\renewcommand*\dictumauthorformat[1]{--- #1}
\renewcommand*\dictumrule{}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\dictum[Lewis Carroll, \emph{Alice in Wonderland}]{Begin at the beginning, the King said gravely, ``and go on till you come to the end: then stop.''}

\end{document}
```

Option 2:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\setkomafont{dictumtext}{\itshape\small}
\setkomafont{dictumauthor}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\dictumwidth{.75\linewidth}
\renewcommand*\dictumauthorformat[1]{--- #1}
\renewcommand*\dictumrule{}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\dictum[Lewis Carroll, \emph{Alice in Wonderland}]{Begin at the beginning, the King said gravely, ``and go on till you come to the end: then stop.''}

\end{document}
```

Option 3:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dictum}[2][]{\par%
  \begingroup
    \raggeddictum\parbox{\dictumwidth}{%
      {\@dictumfont{\raggeddictumtext #2\strut\par}%
        \def\@tempa{#1}\ifx\@tempa\@empty\else%
          {\raggeddictumtext\dictumrule}%
          \raggeddictumauthor\@dictumauthorfont\dictumauthorformat{#1}%
          \strut\par%
        \fi%
      }%
    }\par%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand*{\dictumrule}{}
\newcommand*{\dictumwidth}{.75\textwidth}
\newcommand*{\raggeddictum}{\raggedleft}
\newcommand*{\dictumauthorformat}[1]{--- #1}
\newcommand*{\raggeddictumtext}{\raggedright}
\newcommand*{\raggeddictumauthor}{\raggedleft}
\newcommand*{\@dictumfont}{\itshape\small}
\newcommand*{\@dictumauthorfont}{\normalfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\dictum[Lewis Carroll, \emph{Alice in Wonderland}]{Begin at the beginning, the King said gravely, ``and go on till you come to the end: then stop.''}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A downvote? I always prefer to ask or comment rather than downvote :)

Comment: The down-vote was mine, by accident :( After I posted ny answer I was in a hurry and I though I clicked the up-voting arrow in your answer, but ended up clicking the down-vote arrow. Now I try to reverse the down-vote but I get a message saying "You last voted on this answer 9 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." Can you please edit the answer so I can correct my mistake?

Comment: Done. I'm glad it was a mistake :)

Comment: Thanks. I've undone the down-vote, and corrected the mistake. I'll delete my comments in some hours.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina We don't have the same notion of "Some hours"