# Why am I getting "\dictumrule undefined." or "Undefined control sequence. \dictumrule" error?

Tags: errors, koma-script, windows

I realize this is a bit specific, but this is the only KOMA-Script command that has consistently produced an error, and it's driving me nuts because I can't find a solution anywhere (and I'm usually pretty thorough). I am using TeXstudio on Windows as my environment, which comes with KOMA built-in.

---

**[Final Update]** See answer posted by touhami.

---

Here is a bit of code pulled straight from this question `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193178/specific-epigraph-style`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setkomafont{dictumtext}{\itshape\small}
\setkomafont{dictumauthor}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\dictumwidth{.75\linewidth}
\renewcommand*\dictumauthorformat[1]{--- #1}
\renewcommand*\dictumrule{}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\dictum[Lewis Carroll, \emph{Alice in Wonderland}]{Begin at the beginning, the King said gravely, ``and go on till you come to the end: then stop.''}

\end{document}
```

And this is the error message when compiled:

`\dictumrule undefined. \renewcommand*\dictumrule`

If I were to instead put `\dictumrule` just somewhere in the document, the more common form of the error appears:

`Undefined control sequence. \dictumrule`

In terms of errors related to `\dictumrule` specifically, the only one I've found from my searching has been the one from this question from a LyX help site `http://t101479.editors-lyx-general.editortalk.info/changing-the-dictum-style-in-koma-script-t101479.html`:

`command \dictumrule already defined`

This is nearly the exact opposite of my problem, so not particularly helpful.

My intent is to put a quotation at the beginning of an article between the title and the main text. I am fully aware that I can achieve this same result using `\epigraph` (which I will do if no working solution can be gained here), but I have invested too much energy figuring out this problem to give it up without discovering some kind of solution.

**[Update]** In response to touhami's answer: My apologies that I didn't give more detail for exactly what I want to accomplish.

Here is code using the `epigraph` package that roughly mimics the output of the previous code.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.75\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\epigraph{\itshape\small Begin at the beginning, the King said gravely, ``and go on till you come to the end: then stop.''}{Lewis Carroll, \emph{Alice in Wonderland}}

\end{document}
```

What I actually want is to eliminate the rule between the quotation and author. For the `epigraph` package, I would just add

```
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
```

to the preamble to get

[image: Lewis Carroll quotation]
Theoretically, to make this same change for `\dictum` I would replace

```
\renewcommand*\dictumrule{}
```

with

```
\newcommand*{\dictumrule}{\vskip-1ex\hrulefill\par}
\renewcommand*\dictumrule{0pt}
```

This, however, produces

[image: Lewis Carroll quotation]

I did not say this initially because I assumed this was just a symptom of the underlying error.

**[Update2]** @touhami

This is exactly what I have in the editor after following @egreg's suggestion:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setkomafont{dictumtext}{\itshape\small}
\setkomafont{dictumauthor}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\dictumwidth{.75\linewidth}
\renewcommand*\dictumauthorformat[1]{--- #1}
\providecommand\dictumrule{}
\renewcommand*{\dictumrule}{}

\begin{document}

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \dictum[Lewis Carroll, \emph{Alice in Wonderland}]{Begin at the beginning, the King said gravely, ``and go on till you come to the end: then stop.''}

\end{document}
```

and the output I get is the exact same as the one **with** the rule above.

How do I get rid of the rule?

Comment: i don't get such error with `scrbook 2013/12/19 v3.12`  i think this command is  not defined 
befor v3.10

Comment: if you can't update your package here is the definition `\newcommand{\dictumrule}{\vskip -1ex\hrulefill \par}`

Comment: @touhami I can confirm that the MWE compile at my system Win 7+Mixtex+KOMAScript 3.18. Your two comments are a good answer. I suggest you convert them to an answer.

Comment: I don't get any errors with your example.

Comment: see egreg's comment to my answer. `\dictumrule` is not a length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPdated** Koma-script doc

[image]

```
\newcommand*{\dictumrule}{\vskip-1ex\hrulefill\par}
```

So updating the package will solve the probleme.

Comment: Maybe better: `\providecommand\dictumrule{}\renewcommand*{\dictumrule}{}`, which would work also after an update.

Comment: @touhami @egreg Using the new code provided to replace `\renewcommand*\dictumrule{}` produces the exact same result as the one at the end of my question. Also, if `\dictumrule`is not a length, how do you eliminate the rule? Using `0` or `-1` or `null` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @Johnboy in your case you can use`\newcommand*\dictumrule{}` but this will cause problem  if you update your package since `\dictumrule` will be defined by the package and you can not use `\newcommand` you will need `\renewcommand`  that's why egreg gives a claver solution.

Comment: @touhami I'm afraid I am still not following you.
In the first example code from my question that begins
`\documentclass{scrbook}

\setkomafont{dictumtext}{\itshape\small}
\setkomafont{dictumauthor}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\dictumwidth{.75\linewidth}
...`
if you replace `\renewcommand*\dictumrule{}` with either
`\newcommand*{\dictumrule}{\vskip-1ex\hrulefill\par}
\renewcommand*\dictumrule{}`
OR
`\newcommand*\dictumrule{}`
OR
`\providecommand\dictumrule{}
\renewcommand*{\dictumrule}{}`
they all produce the same result - with a visible rule - like the one shown at end of my question.

Comment: @Johnboy yes and that's what i am trying to say but only the last one is recommanded the first 2 will cause problem if you update your package or if you share your document with someone like me

Comment: @touhami ok, then how do I get rid of the rule? That solution by itself doesn't do it.

Comment: @Johnboy oooohh i'm really sorry, the 3 solution make no rule if you have rule make sure your preambl is the same

Comment: @touhami Since I don't know how to decently format in a comment, see Update2 in my question.

Comment: @Johnboy your update2 don't produce rule for me. What happen if you comment `\providecommand\dictumrule{} \renewcommand*{\dictumrule}{}`? may scrbook have a rule by defaut in earlier version

Comment: @touhami Commenting both those lines produces the exact same result.

Comment: @Johnboy so update your package and use your first code.

Comment: Wow, well that's what you get when you don't do the most obvious step first, UPDATE! Turns out that not only was koma-script way out of date, but so was MiKTeX. I updated both and now `\renewcommand*{\dictumrule}{}` works just as it should, `\dictumrule` produces no errors. Sorry for the runaround you all, you were still very helpful. @touhami please edit your answer, maybe with a final update and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @Johnboy answer edited.