# Chapter Mini-Toc: 19th Century Styles

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a package which facilitates the creation of 19th-century style mini-ToC's at the beginning of each chapter? Also, what is this section called? (the italicized text referring to the LOTR and not bacon).

I recall seeing a post about this, but I can't find it, the mini-ToC questions refer to different styles.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=5.in:8.in,DIV=15,BCOR=12mm,headings=small, ]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{EB Garamond 12 Regular} % works

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{setspace}
%\leading{6.5mm}
\clubpenalty = 7500
\widowpenalty = 7500
\displaywidowpenalty = 7500

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{\textbf{Foreword}}
\singlespace
\textit {Discovery of the Ring • Bilbo tries it on • Frodo steals the Ring from Bilbo • Gandalf sees the Ring • Gandalf Kills Frodo • Gandalf Challenges Sauron}

\vspace{1cm}

Bacon ipsum dolor amet alcatra t-bone tongue strip steak, flank doner meatloaf pastrami brisket. Buffalo capicola cupim ground round pork fatback sirloin biltong andouille spare ribs rump filet mignon shoulder. Biltong meatball pig, ground round sausage tri-tip ribeye cow. Beef flank strip steak cow pork belly ground round landjaeger. Flank boudin short loin, doner turkey bresaola strip steak shankle tongue corned beef kielbasa chuck pork belly landjaeger meatloaf.

Fatback porchetta venison buffalo frankfurter chicken pastrami landjaeger cupim andouille corned beef. Chuck bresaola pork chop pancetta porchetta biltong. Short ribs drumstick kielbasa, tongue ham hock biltong beef jerky hamburger venison bresaola. Pork belly ball tip capicola flank sausage hamburger shank corned beef meatloaf. Turducken sirloin landjaeger biltong andouille sausage. Beef ribs fatback pork chop chicken capicola hamburger meatloaf sausage brisket filet mignon ball tip ribeye frankfurter alcatra. Tongue jerky bresaola, rump ribeye kielbasa boudin chislic cupim pork belly burgdoggen.

Drumstick venison turkey tail chuck leberkas. Filet mignon pastrami pork chop, cow andouille alcatra ground round strip steak capicola fatback bresaola. Pork belly biltong porchetta chicken meatball. Swine picanha brisket capicola salami. Tenderloin pork belly short ribs ham hock turkey turducken ground round corned beef flank chuck chicken meatloaf fatback. Buffalo burgdoggen short loin, corned beef kevin andouille capicola beef filet mignon fatback rump ribeye shankle chuck turducken. Biltong chuck pork chop meatloaf.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `titletoc`, but I'm not sure it is compatible with KOMA.

Comment: A headnote. Like an epigraph, in terms of form and location. KOMA seems to have a `dictum` command: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193178/specific-epigraph-style